# foreach в функции

Tags: c++

Подскажите пожалуйста почему такая запись выдаёт ошибку. "не найдена соответствующая функция begin, необходимая для этого основанного на диапазоне оператора for"

```
int func(int arr[]) {   
    for (auto &var : arr) //
        std::cout << var << std::endl;
}
```

хотя вот такая запись работает

```
int main() {
    int arr[] = { 5,11,99,54 };

    for (auto &var : arr)
        std::cout << var << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Джентльмены, у кого есть время и вдохновение - напишите хороший вопрос и не менее хороший ответ, чтоб можно было закрывать такие вопросы как дубли...

Comment: укажите размерность в скобках - вроде как должно заработать.

Comment: а если размерность мне не известна

Answer (score 4):

Потому что в первом случае `arr` представляет собой указатель на `int` и не несет в себе никаких сведений о размере массива.

Во втором случае `arr` - это реально массив. Размер которого компилятору известен.

```
int func(int arr[], int n) {   
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) //
        std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: подскажи пожалуйста как исправить?

Comment: мне не известен размер массива передаваемого в функцию

Comment: Тогда приплыли :) Только я не понимаю, в каком **реальном** случае это может быть... И если уж вы не знаете - то откуда ж знать компилятору? :)

Comment: решил задачу, посмотри может быть что добавишь.

Comment: Нормальное решение. Просто изначально ни слова не говорилось о возможности использовать шаблоны, да и опять же - в этом случае (когда будет работать шаблон), вы **знаете** размер массива. Так что применим и метод с передачей указателя и размера (например, как `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])`) . Ну, а что вам больше подходит - это уже дело ваше.

Answer (score 3):

Вот решил задачу. Поправте меня если этот код не так хорошь как кажеться. Хотя работает как нужно.

```
template <size_t N>
void foo(int(&arr)[N])
{
    for (int var : arr)
    {
        printf("%d\n", var);
    }
}
```

Comment: Нет, все правильно, единственный способ передать сишный массив в качестве аргумента.

Comment: ну вот почему все читают книги по си, когда учат с++? Написано же в нормальных книгах массивы в с++ - это std::vector (ну и std::array для тех, кто понимает). Все остально должно использоваться только в особых случаях. Обучение навыкам программирования на с++ не есть особый случай.